# Simple for loop to add columns to dataframes in a list not working, what is going on?

Tags: r

I am new to R but not to programming. I know there is probably a function that does this already, but I want to know why this does not work.

```
grids <- list(grid_all_2011,grid_all_2017,grid_tenyear_2011,grid_tenyear_2017)
for (i in seq_along(grids)) {
  grids[[i]]$test <- "test"
}
```

The output is just an object with the name i, it doesn't add the test column to any of the dataframes.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; when I run this code using `mtcars` in place of each data frame, it works fine.

Comment: Please add a sample dataset (smaller version of your data, using `dput()`, and importantly, mention the error that you're getting. It's important for others to see what the problem is, then the community can help you!

Comment: I guess I know what you might have misunderstood. The list "grid" does not contain pointers to the "grid_all_" data.frames but their copies. Your code changes only the copies inside the list.

Comment: if you wish to add columns to a dataframe, one would normally use the `cbind()` function

Comment: @massisenergy there is no error; it is doing something, just not what you would expect. I don't think this has anything to do with the data.

Comment: @GradaGukovic Well now I am confused, why does it point to a copy and not to the actual dataframes? How do I make it point to the actual dataframes

Comment: @Momchill That is all well and go, though not what I am asking. I am not concerned with the adding of the columns, its a minor thing. My concern is why is this for loop not working, it should. If i just do this for each dataframe individually the body of the loop works no problem.

Comment: @KarlJohnson is this data of yours sharable? Kinda hard to figure out what's going wrong like this.

Comment: Just an fyi, @GradaGukovic's suggestion is incorrect about the whole "pointing to copies" thing. The fact that your code works perfectly fine for me with different data sets strongly suggests that one of two things is going on: (1) There is something particularly odd about your data frames (maybe they aren't even data frames), or (2) There are other objects/packages in your R session impacting things that you haven't mentioned; you could try in a fresh session.

Comment: @Momchill no unfortunately, but let's assume the data is fine and it is something else. I neglected to mention that I am using tidyverse and used read_csv to bring the data in, so I think these are tibbles, not dataframes exactly (not sure if that matters or not).

Comment: @joran Thanks for clearing that up. I neglected to mention I am using tidyverse, and used read_csv to bring the data in; so I think the data are stored in tibbles not dataframes exactly. Other than that I do not have any other packages or objects loaded in.

Comment: The tibble/data frame distinction should not make a difference in this case, but we're pretty much at a dead end here unless you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @ joran, @ Karl Johnson.I didnt say it contained pointers, or pointers to copies. I said it containes independent copies. Where did you check whether there is a test collumn? In the elements of the list (i.e. grids[1:4]) or in the data.frames( grid_all_2011, ...). You'li findit in the first place and not in the second. 
Appropos data.table is a subclass of data.frame so it doesnt make a difference here